# assign a cache profile for authenticated users

Tags: 70-667, output-cache, cache

You have a SharePoint Server 2010 server farm.

You need to assign a cache profile for authenticated users.

What should you do?

- A.From Site Settings, modify the Site Collection output cache.
- B.From Site Settings, modify the Site Collection cache profiles.

Which answer is correct?

I thought B is correct but in another pdf file it says A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because the direct link "Site Collection Cache Profiles" under Site Collection administration is all about Defining NEW cache profiles, not setting one. To configure it (chose which one) you use "Site Output Cache" in the Site Collection, where you can chose from predefined profiles.

It is the difference between, defining the profile, versus applying it, as you could create these profiles, and use them.

Comment: So assign cashe profile is by modify output cache?

Comment: You have 2 steps: 1. Define your Cache profile settings (using Site Collection Cache Profiles) and 2. Apply that Cache profile (per Site Collection or Sub-Site more specific, via the Site collection output cache, respectivelly Site Output Cache). Hope is clear now. See more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa661294.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the answer must be B as i can see the option to enable cache profiles in site settings. sp2010

Site collection cache profiles 
Site collection object cache 
Site collection output cache